# Magento Menu: How can I get it to align left?

Tags: css, magento, menu, themes, megamenu

Two problem plaguing me for a few hours now.  I want to get my menu text to left align and also would like to increase the text size sub cats in the menu

http://www.acuity-sports.com/

Any help on what I need to edit would be great.

Here is my .css for the header

```
#yt_menuwrap {  background: url(../images/bkg_main_nav.png) left 53px repeat-x;  margin-   top: -51px;  }

#yt_mainnav,
#yt_mainnav_mobi {  display:table; margin: 0 auto;  }

#yt_mainnav_mobi select { margin:0;   }

#menu_split {  clear: left;  }

.header-top {        height: 78px;   /*  position: relative;     z-index:3; */ } 

.main-top{  }

.main-top .herader-top{ background:none; }

.header-logo { position:absolute; top:0; }

.header-logo a { position:relative;  width:auto; height:auto; }

.header-bottom { height: 70px;  /*  position:relative; z-index: 4; */ box-shadow: 0 0   3px 2px #CCC; }

.header-cirlce{ position:relative; text-align:center; height:0px;  z-index:1;  display:none; }

.header-cirlce .inner-circle{ width:193px; height:57px; display:inline-block; position:relative; overflow:hidden; }

.header-cirlce .inner-circle .header-circle-logo{
position:absolute;  
width:210px;
height:210px;   
border-radius:225px;    
background-position:21% 54%;
box-shadow:3px 0px 7px 0 #000000;
z-index:1;    
left:-10px;top:-160px;
```

}

```
.header-cirlce .inner-circle .header-circle-content{
position:absolute;
bottom:14px;
left:5px;
width:180px;
height:50px;
display:inline-block;
z-index:2;
background:url(../images/bg-circle-logo.png) no-repeat center center transparent;
```

}

Comment: What did you mean by "menu text to left align"? You want the menu items to start from the left of the page?

Comment: Yes it is currently centered by default I assume due to the theme.  I'm trying to get the text to left align.

Comment: Well to do that you will have to make lot of css changes starting from `div .container` which has a `width` of `1170px` in the media query for `device min-width 1200px`. Like this you will have to change lot of other css and that too check how it respond for different devices.

Comment: I will keep searching around for some answers.  I thought I knew what file to start editing, but now im so confused where to start again.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it thank god..

I had to edit my theme.css

```
#yt_mainnav,
#yt_mainnav_mobi {  display:table; margin: 0 auto;  }
```

and remove the 0 auto;

to this

```
#yt_mainnav,
#yt_mainnav_mobi {  display:table; margin: }
```